# Vim thinks Python @ operator is decorator

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-python, python

Python3 has the matrix multiplication operator (`@`) which is used to multiply `numpy` matrices. But when we write something like `A = B @ C` in vim, the `@ C` portion gets highlighted. Apparently Python has these things called decorators which also use `@`. Vim's syntax highlighting seems to confuse the operator for the decorator. We basically want the following:

```
A = B@C     # <-- Operator, this should look just like B+C

A = B \
@C          # <-- Still operator, '\' makes it multi-line

@D          # <-- Decorator, should be highlighted
```

The culprit seems to be this line from the `python.vim` file (I used the latest version from [here](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790)):

```
syn match   pythonDecorator "@" display nextgroup=pythonDottedName skipwhite
```

It doesn't check if the `@` is being used as an operator.

So I have two questions.

1. How to get vim to highlight correctly?
2. How to do this without mucking around with `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim` (or whatever system file is being used)?

I don't think I will be using decorators, so one option is to just comment out the offending line above. But this requires us to manipulate system files.

Comment: No need to comment it out in the system files. If you’re certain you never want decorators highlighted you can instead add `syntax clear pythonDecorator` to `.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` to remove the syntax item.

Comment: Note that this was [fixed in Vim 8.0.0055 in 2016](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b4ada79/runtime/syntax/python.vim#L111-L129); you may want to consider using a newer Vim version (that last regexp scares me btw). You can also copy the newer syntax file to `~/.vim/syntax/python.vim` to override the default one, which should probably work (unless it uses newer Vim features, I didn't check/test).

Comment: @MartinTournoij That's an answer if I know one... Would you mind turning it into an actual answer? Thanks! (Also, yeah, scary regex! I'm glad it was someone else's job to figure that one out.) 

Comment: Akhil, if the answer below answers your question, you can [accept it](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate that it answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin points out in the comments, [this has been fixed](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b4ada79aa7d0d1e5da3a659b1a203d7cae9f7f59/runtime/syntax/python.vim). Either update vim or add the newer syntax file to your configuration.